# php date convert functions problems with month and day value

Tags: php, sql, date, datetime

I receive date values from web form in format dd/mm/YY (jquery datepicker) exmp: 13/07/2014

```
$date_from = $_POST['date_from'];
$date_to = $_POST['date_to'];

$newdate1 = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime($date_from));
$newdate2 = date("Y-m-d 23:59:59", strtotime($date_to));
```

i need print all records from db where date is between this two dates:

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE date BETWEEN '$newdate1' AND '$newdate2'"
```

It work fine until today because when i try select todays date 13/04/1014 (in jquery) and convert to format Y-m-d 00:00:00 script thinks 13 is month and return date `1970-01-01`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) expects to be given a string containing an **English** date format.

A basic solution is convert your format in english format

```
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', '13/07/2014');
```

output

```
13-07-2014
```

in your code

```
$date_from = $_POST['date_from'];
$date_to = $_POST['date_to'];

$newdate1 = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00",strtotime(date('d-m-Y', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $date_from)))));
$newdate2 = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00",strtotime(date('d-m-Y', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $date_to)))));
```

Answer (score 1):

As the format required in the SQL query is different then the input format then it will create issues on multiple dates. Its better to convert your date to the appropriate format first and then run the query.

```
<?php
//Creating a function to convert date to required format
function formattedDate($dateStr, $inputFormat, $outputFormat) {
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat($inputFormat, $dateStr);
    echo $date->format($outputFormat);
}

//Get input
$date_from = $_POST['date_from'];
$date_to = $_POST['date_to'];

//Get formatted date values
$newdate1 = formattedDate($date_from, "d/m/Y", "Y-m-d H:i:s");
$newdate2 = formattedDate($date_to, "d/m/Y", "Y-m-d H:i:s");
?>
```

Comment: @user3747585: and what is that ?